# How to add file to QT resource file from code?

Tags: qt, resources

I want to add image, which was chosen by user in File Dialog, to resource file. I tried to find something in documentation, but without success. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resource files are compiled into your applications binary, they can't be modified at run-time like this.